# Logback java configuration in runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I need create a lot of .log file in different folders from one java method.

Example:

> home/work/folder1/log1.log
>
> home/work/folder1/log2.log
>
> home/work/folder2/log3.log
>
> ...............................

In java method i create dynamic Logger:

```
private Logger getLogger(String extId, String workId) {
    String postfix = String.join(
        ".",
        getClass().getName(),
        extId, //folder1, folder2
        String.valueOf(workId) //log1, log2
    );
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(postfix);
}
```

How i can configurate logback to runtime create files?

I see *ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator*, but don't inderstand what do next.

Thank for any helps!

Comment: So you want separate file per logger? You can just include logger name in file appender configuration in logback.xml

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how many loggers/folder i will have. It's dynamic. I must do it without xml

Comment: It does not matter. You just use logger name placeholder in file name.

Comment: Can you show some example please?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care about your log folders?
You can log in one folder and use the elk-stack to verify them. 
I always do it with one sperate folder per log level and configure my logpattern with log4j2. Logstash reads the logs immediatly when new ones are available und pushes them to elastic search. With kibana you can do many cool dashboards to analyze them.